# Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename on migrate db rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am dealing with this error when I try to migrate the database. The folders have the "full access" permissions and I tried to change the environment but it does not work.

```
C:\Users\johnerik.rodriguezbe\dev\mmog-le>rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (C:/Users/johnerik.rodriguezbe/dev/mmog-le/tmp/cache/bootsnap/load-path-cache.21520.63320.tmp, C:/Users/johnerik.rodriguezbe/dev/mmog-le/tmp/cache/bootsnap/load-path-cache)
C:/Users/johnerik.rodriguezbe/dev/mmog-le/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code or log output. Instead, please edit your question and add the actual log output as code-formatted text to your question.

Comment: Hi Holger, thanks for your reply. Do you know what could be the cause of this problem?